# SQL - using SET with a variable table value

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1,@max INT,@table nvarchar(100),@academic nvarchar(100)

SELECT @max = max(id)
FROM #tablelist

WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @max)
BEGIN
   SET @table = (SELECT TABLE_NAME
   FROM #tablelist WHERE id = @LoopCounter) 

        SET @academic = (SELECT F6
   FROM @table WHERE F5 = Academic) 

   SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1        
END
```

where #tablelist is a list of all my tables in the database that are relevent.

The step:

```
    SET @academic = (SELECT F6
   FROM @table WHERE F5 = Academic)
```

does not work... I've tried with sp_execute but I get thrown back standard errors, at the moment the error is 'Must declare the standard variable '@table'. I have also tried an EXEC but it doesn't like that either.

What I want to do is define @academic to be a value from the @table The problem I'm having is the SET does not like being from @table.

Any help would be fab!

Comment: I suggest you start over. Dynamic sql is probably in your future but it may be over your head. The short answer is you did not define a variable named (at)table so you can't use it. The error should be obvious. But you cannot parameterize object names - which is what you are trying to do with the statements that follow your attempted assignment. A simple web (or SO) search on "search all columns" will find many examples of similar logic that you can adapt to your purpose. That would be an easier start I think.

Comment: And one more comment. A while loop like this is just a more complicated and error-prone version of a cursor. If you need a cursor, just use one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1,
        @max INT,@table nvarchar(100),
        @academic nvarchar(100);

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);;

SELECT @max = max(id)
FROM #tablelist;

WHILE(@LoopCounter <= @max)
BEGIN
    SET @table = (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM #tablelist WHERE id = @LoopCounter) ;
    SET @SQL = '
SELECT @academic = F6
FROM [table]
WHERE f5 = 'Academic'
';

    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '[Table]', @table_name);

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                       N'@academic NVARCHAR(100)',
                       @academic=@academic;

    SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter + 1        
END;
```

All that said, this is not an example of good coding (even ignoring the fact that I'm not escaping the table name).

You should not have multiple tables with the same columns, distinguished only by a variant of the name.  Instead, you should have a *single* table with all the rows, and perhaps an additional column or two for identifying the columns.

Having to use dynamic SQL can illustrate a problem with the data model.  And in this case, I think that it does.